# How can I substitute null values by average values in PYSPARK?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

How can I substitute null values in the column `col1` by average values? There is, however, the following condition:

```
id   col1
1    12
1    NaN
1    14
1    10
2    22
2    20
2    NaN
3    NaN
3    NaN
```

The NaN values for `id=1` should be substituted by the mean of `col1` calculated over `id=1`, which is `12` ((12+14+10)/3)). The same applies to `id=2`. The cases such as `id=3` can be ignored and NaN can be left.

This is what I tried:

```
calcul = df.groupby("id").agg(func.mean("col1"))

df = df.withColumn("col1", func.when((df["col1"].isNull()), calcul.where(func.col("id")==df["id"])).otherwise(func.col("col1")))
```

PLEASE REMOVE DUPLICATE TAG FOR PANDAS. I USE PYSPARK.

Comment: @Chris: It's not pandas. It's pyspark.

Comment: Ah my bad :P Sorry for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First drop `null` from you original dataframe and groupby `id` and take average:

```
df_ave = df1.dropna().groupby('id').agg(F.mean('col1').alias('mean'))
df_ave.show()
```

Output:

```
+---+----+
| id|mean|
+---+----+
|  1|12.0|
|  2|21.0|
+---+----+
```

Then join it with your original dataframe:

```
df1 = df1.join(df_ave, on='id', how='left')
df1.show()
```

Output:

```
+---+----+----+
| id|col1|mean|
+---+----+----+
|  1|12.0|12.0|
|  1| NaN|12.0|
|  1|14.0|12.0|
|  1|10.0|12.0|
|  3| NaN|null|
|  3| NaN|null|
|  2|22.0|21.0|
|  2|20.0|21.0|
|  2| NaN|21.0|
+---+----+----+
```

Then use the following `when` statement and create your new column `col1_new`:

```
df1 = df1.withColumn('col1_new', F.when( df1.col1=='NaN', df1.mean).otherwise(df1.col1))
df1.show()
```

Output:

```
+---+----+----+--------+
| id|col1|mean|col1_new|
+---+----+----+--------+
|  1|12.0|12.0|    12.0|
|  1| NaN|12.0|    12.0|
|  1|14.0|12.0|    14.0|
|  1|10.0|12.0|    10.0|
|  3| NaN|null|    null|
|  3| NaN|null|    null|
|  2|22.0|21.0|    22.0|
|  2|20.0|21.0|    20.0|
|  2| NaN|21.0|    21.0|
+---+----+----+--------+
```

You can also drop unwanted columns and rename `col1_new` to `col1`.

```
df1 = df1.select('id', 'col1_new').withColumnRenamed('col1_new', 'col1')
df1.show()
```

Output:

```
+---+----+
| id|col1|
+---+----+
|  1|12.0|
|  1|12.0|
|  1|14.0|
|  1|10.0|
|  3|null|
|  3|null|
|  2|22.0|
|  2|20.0|
|  2|21.0|
+---+----+
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a join is inefficient.

I'd recommend using a [Window](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.Window) with [pyspark.sql.functions.mean](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.mean):

```
from pyspark.sql import Window
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, mean, when

df = df.withColumn(
    "col1",
    when(
        col("col1").isNull(), 
        mean("col1").over(Window.partitionBy("id"))
    ).otherwise(col("col1"))
)
```